# Firebase/Google cloud functions - is it possible to hook into cloud functions error event?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to hook into Firebase/google cloud functions `uncaughtException` event - something like `process.on('uncaughtException')`?

**Background**

Using error tracking tools like Raygun, Sentry, StackHunter etc. can improve the develop experience tremendously as you can centralize error handling, and don't wait for users to report when something is broken.

Most error handling tools executes code in a wrapped context, that works great for a try/catch pattern. But to handle uncaught exceptions, access to the Node global error handler is a must.

**Possible workaround**

A solid pattern for wrapping functions? I am experimenting with this (in Sentry and firebase functions), update will follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify how Node.js handles errors, as Google CFs don't allow it [[1]](https://forum.sentry.io/t/google-cloud-functions-client-setup/1970/2).

You can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#errors) how the execution environment handles errors.

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if Firebase you to hook into uncaught exceptions to run error handling code